# How to sort a text file (.json file) where each line is a player name followed by a score

Tags: c#, json, sorting, xna

I am going to make a hall of frame (Top 5 high score) for an XNA game but I'm having some trouble figuring out how. I have AllPlayer.json file to record the name of player and another json file record the detail of paler such as name, score, and so on.
the text file are something like this: (picture) http://upic.me/i/zc/t56v1.jpg

Now I can sort descending but I need only top 5 people

Example:

```
A 100 
B 50
C 30
D 10
E 45
F 55
G 90
```

it should be like this :

```
A 100
G 90
F 55
B 50
E 45
```

Code:

```
List<List<string>> lst = new List<List<string>>();

  lst.Add(new List<string>());
  lst.Add(new List<string>());

for (int i = 0; i < ap.PlayerName.Count; i++)
{

detail = JsonBuilder.DeserializeFromFile<Player>("C:\\VirtualDrumGame\\Player\\" + ap.PlayerName[i] + ".json");

    lst[0].Add(detail.Score.ToString());
    lst[1].Add(detail.PlayerName);

}

 var myComparer = new CustomComparer();

lst[0].Sort((x, y) =>
{
 int ix, iy;
 return int.TryParse(x, out ix) && int.TryParse(y, out iy)
 ? ix.CompareTo(iy) : string.Compare(x, y);
});

 for (int j = lst[0].Count - 1; j <= lst[0].Count - 1; j--)
{

  temp += lst[1][j].ToString() + "  Score: " + lst[0][j].ToString() + "\n";
}
```

I really appreciate the answers!!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe simple use `IEnumerable.Take(<number>)`?

```
var list = new List<int>(){1,3,2,6,9,2,3,5,4,8};
var result = list.OrderByDescending(p => p).Take(5).ToList();
```

or to keep it with your example and making it a little simpler

```
var lst = new List<List<string>>()
{
    new List<string>(){"A","22"},
    new List<string>(){"B","7"},
    new List<string>(){"C","4"},
    new List<string>(){"D","3"},
    new List<string>(){"E","10"},
    new List<string>(){"F","5"},
    new List<string>(){"G","1"},
};

var result = lst.OrderByDescending(p=>Int32.Parse( p[1] )).Take(5);
```

which outputs

```
Player A Score: 22
Player E Score: 10
Player B Score: 7
Player F Score: 5
Player C Score: 4
```

Just to make the sorting a little bit more safe if the int cannot be parsed you could also use

```
var outInt = 0;
var result = lst.OrderByDescending(p =>
            {
                if (Int32.TryParse(p[1], out outInt))
                {
                    return outInt;
                }
                else
                {
                    return -1;
                }
            }).Take(5);
```